# How to get filename whilst copying files in c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, file, copy

I have a simple console app which copies files from one directory to another. The UI allows you to specify source and target directory. The copy functionality works fine however I want to be able to show the file name and path of the file that is currently being copied from source to target. This should render on the UI returning from CopyVM model. Other question is soon after the user clicks on "Copy" button the txtCopyingFile.Text doesn't change the text button to "Copying..."? Thanks for any help

Windows form UI:

```
    private readonly ICopyDirectory copyDirectory;

    public Form1(ICopyDirectory copyDirectory)
    {
        this.copyDirectory = copyDirectory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(copyDirectory));

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.folderSelection(txtSourceDirectory);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.folderSelection(txtTargetDirectory);
    }

    private void folderSelection(TextBox tb)
    {
        var dialogue = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        if (dialogue.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            tb.Text = Path.Combine(dialogue.SelectedPath, Path.GetFileName(tb.Text));
        }
    }

    private async void copyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtCopyingFile.Text = "Copying...";
        await CopyFiles();
        txtCopyingFile.Text = "File copy complete";

    }

    private async Task CopyFiles()
    {
        await copyDirectory.Copy(txtSourceDirectory.Text, txtTargetDirectory.Text);
    }
```

Windows form Program.cs

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var copyDirectory = new CopyDirectory();
        Application.Run(new Form1(copyDirectory));
    }
```

Library:
public interface ICopyDirectory
{
Task Copy(string sourceDirectoryPath, string targetDirectoryPath);
}

```
public class CopyDirectory : ICopyDirectory
{

    public async Task<CopyVM> Copy(string sourceDirectoryPath, string targetDirectoryPath)
    {
        var sourceDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectoryPath);
        var targetDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectoryPath);

        await Task.Run(() => CopyContents(sourceDirectoryInfo, targetDirectoryInfo));

        return new CopyVM
        {
            CopyComplete = true,
            CopyingFileName = "test1",
            CopyingFilePath = "test"
        };
    }

    private async Task CopyContents(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
    {
        foreach (var file in source.GetFiles())
        {
            file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, file.Name), true);
        }

        foreach (var sourceSubdirectory in source.GetDirectories())
        {
            var targetSubdirectory = target.CreateSubdirectory(sourceSubdirectory.Name);
            await CopyContents(sourceSubdirectory, targetSubdirectory);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put an event on CopyDirectory and raise it from the first loop of CopyContents. Such an approach is consistent with the rest of the winforms world; classes that "do stuff anyway" and if you want to observe their changing state, you use an event (textbox textchanged, for example..) but you dont *have* to subscribe to the event

Comment: could you show me how i can implement this please? haven't touched events before